# Chrome not listening to click handler when child element is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have found a scenario where Chrome completely ignores click events when combined with a mouse-enter event.  I am curious if this is a known bug in Chrome or jQuery?

The jsfiddle below shows this example.  If you drag your mouse into a cell from directly above or below the item that is showing the 'hover-add' class, and click on the '.cell-item', the click event *is not* registered.  However, if you come in from the left or right side of the cell, the click event *is* registered.

https://jsfiddle.net/smoq36yp/

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='col' data-col='0'>
    <div class='cell' data-row='2' data-col='0'></div>
    <div class='cell hover-add' data-row='1' data-col='0'>
      <div class='cell-item'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='cell filled' data-row='0' data-col='0'>
      <div class='cell-item'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

# if you move the mouse in from above or below to the cell in row 1,
# this click event (or others put on the body, etc.) does not fire 
$('.cell:not(.filled)').click (event) ->
  mgr.addItem(event)
$('.cell:not(.filled)').mouseenter (event) ->
  mgr.hoverInAddItem(event)
```

Comment: Seems to work for me in chrome v. 51

Comment: Seems to work for me in chrome v. 52

Comment: For some reason the screencast .mov wouldn't load in browser until I did this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205081  Maybe it's because you uploaded the .mov direcly to screencast. Jing https://www.techsmith.com/jing.html is screencast's free tool to do video screen captures and it'll work seemlessly on screencast.com I use SnagIt https://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html which is the paid version of jing with slightly more features (annotation and more). HTH!

Comment: @gaetanoM I also updated the jsfiddle to make this easier to repeat

Comment: @Adjit updated my description to be clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue with the JSFiddle link.

When I add `.cell-item {pointer-events: none;}`, I'm seeing the desired behavior.

Chrome's event handler (and/or jQuery?) seems to be getting confused once the `.cell-item` is added to the `.cell`. Am seeing other odd behavior once the hover item is added; multiple 'mouseenter' events triggering while over hover item, and 'click' is oddly triggering 'mouseenter'. May be able to alternatively resolve by binding click items on the `.cell-item` as well, but I didn't explore that since the little bit of CSS above fixes it for me.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works, thanks!  I would still love to know why Chrome / jquery has this odd behavior!